# Pandas Setting all values in column in color

Tags: python, pandas

For a new column in pandas, I want to set every value in red when I have the value 1.
comp_df.loc[comp_df["comp_ad"] == 1].

I already tried it, but I have an error

```
comp_df.style.applymap(lambda x: "background-color: red" if comp_df['comp_ad'] == 1)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if-else` statement with `subset` parameter for test column `comp_ad`:

```
(comp_df.style
        .applymap(lambda x: "background-color: red" if x == 1 else "", subset=['comp_ad'])
        .to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl'))
```